# IOS UITableView right half cut off screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

For some reason, no matter what I do, when I create a static tableview inside a UITableViewController, put content into the cells and run the simulator the right half of the screen is always cut off and I don't know why. Ive tried making new projects and remaking the storyboard but nothings working.

Here's what it looks like when I run the app

[image]

heres what the storyboard looks like.
[image]

I have content set to static cells

**Anyone run into this problem or know how to fix it via storyboard (or programmatically but not preferred)?**

**Update:**

Here are some more pictures of what another project looks like when I run it:

[image]

and here's what the storyboard looks like

[image]

Comment: Can't, the tableview is not contained within a view therefore you can't set constraints. If I put it inside a view then I can no longer make the tableviews content static, therefore I cant put it inside another view.

Comment: ohh yes ... set constraint to right button ...

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what you mean by "set constraint to right button"

Comment: you have to learn autolayout ... to make app compatible with all screen sizes ...

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of the scaling of the device on the simulator (Window -> Scale). Try setting it to 50% or even less.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give constraints to your right button...

For that select your button and pin its edges to `right, top, bottom and give width` constraint like below

[image]

and here is [autolayout tutorial link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) .. you can check that

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the problem. I've updated my post with more photos of my other project with these changes, but it still appears the same.

Comment: this is different layout ... and its too broad ... you need to learn autolayout... thats the only solution

Comment: I tested your thing out with my other layout and it did work, so im just going to redo the layout with your margins setup. Thanks!

Comment: @Minimi ok .. glad it   helps .. .and check that link its really helpfil

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem in giving constraints to the table not for the button.
Try giving constraints to the table like "leading space to superview,trailing space to superview,top space and bottom space to superview

Edit:
The above solution given by me might fix for tableview inside UIViewcontroller.

Comment: its tableview controller ...  you can not set constraint to tableview controller as it by default pinned with all edges

Comment: oh yeah..i did not see its tableviewcontroller..Thanks.